# Subsequent shipping charge via Reference Transaction

Tags: paypal

We're building a site with PayPal *Payments Pro* and the client would like to issue shipping charges after the payment for merchandise once the exact shipping charge is known.

Reading around it sounds like [Reference Transactions](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns) may be the answer here.

According to [this article](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business-Archive/Reference-Transactions/td-p/487070) it sounds like an admin could login and initiate a charge (given the use of a *Reference Transaction* API call to begin with.. *I think..*  Or perhaps the call isn't needed if we're planning to use the PayPal admin).

Is this possible?  Do we even need a *Reference Transaction* API call, or do we just need to be approved for *Reference Transactions*, given the plan to issue subsequent shipping charges through the PayPal admin interface?

Please don't answer by suggesting payment calculators or flat rate shipping charges.  The question is how to implement a subsequent shipping charge via PayPal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you do a reference transaction through API or through the PayPal Admin, you would still need to have reference transactions enabled on your account.  Also depending on if you are referring to DoDirectPayment credit card payments or Express Checkout, you will need to pass over additional variables your initial Express Checkout API call to set up a billing agreement so that you can perform reference transactions later.

Also I don't the specifics around how you calculate shipping, but another method that may allow you to calculate this correctly if if your shipping provider has API's to connect to their system to calculate the shipping charges.  Then at the time of checkout, you could use use the [Callback AP](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/callback-api-operation-nvp)I to calculate the shipping while they are checkout out with Express Checkout.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I don't see anywhere in the docs describing how to setup an agreement via Payments Pro.  There's a description of [how to run a reference transaction](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/doreferencetransaction-api-operation-nvp), but no indication of how to setup the agreement in the first place.  The [preapproval operation](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/preapproval-api-operation) requires customers to establish a PayPal account.  Do *reference transactions* have the same requirement?

Comment: For reference transactions via credit card, there is not payment agreement needed.  It would just be a API call for the do reference.  However, if your buyers are using Express Checkout and paying with their PayPal account, this is where you would need to set up a billing agreement.  This is mentioned in the Set Express Checkout section of the developers guide.

Comment: Thanks for this, figured as much and realized I'd not stated that we're using Payments Pro in the question; I'll revise once I have a chance.